# Site's content in different screens

Tags: javascript, html, resolution, stretch

I'm kinda new at creating a website using scripts, css ant etc. but I think that I'm doing well already... Now I came to the place where I need to make my site looking good in different screen resolution (monitor). So now I have something like this: (deleted link due of reputation lack) boxes are my site's content and I want this to look like that one: http://ipix.lt/di/BH2C/stretched.png content is stretched to the end of browser size and monitor size... What should I do to make my content a little bit bigger, or lower for lower screen monitors? I have already done width to 100%, but don't know what to do more, maybe where's some javascripts? Thanks! And sorry for my English, wanted to make it more clearer...

EDIT. Okay, so there's my site http://pingvinasus.tumblr.com/, yeah it's a blog which I edit in html... Now I managed to make my every content in percents, would be 20%, sooo it will stretch. But I can't do that because I have extra spaces after every of my post, tried to edit css, but can't find that correct margin, tried changing everything there, but it looks like it's not event css... So any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think [Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries) is what you are looking for.

Here is a simple example

[Check this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Slico/cpjygnyf/1/)

```
@media (min-width: 700px) { 
   .color{
       background-color: red;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your pictures, it looks like you have margins and paddings set. set them to 0px!important and like Slico says, ensure your media queries are intact.